# pidof command produces no output

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, pid

Using Ubuntu 14.04
Trying to use the `pidof` command it does not produce any output (no errors).

Tried with `-x` option also no output.

Does it mean the process is not running?

Answer (score 0):

> Does it mean the process is not running?

That's correct, `pidof(1)` prints the PIDs of processes matching the request. You can also use the exit code: `0` means that at least one process was found, `1` means that no process was found.

Comment: @Fredrik If I do a `ps ax | grep dse` I do get the pid with stat S+. So the process is running. But when I do a `pidof dse` or `pidof -x dse` I get nothing.

Comment: @Sam-T could you post the output of `ps ax | grep dse`? `pidof(1)` tries to match against `/proc/<PID>/cmdline` or the program linked to by `/proc/<PID>/exe`. See https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/master/pidof.c#L185 for an implementation, so maybe the process is renamed to `dse` after it starts?

Comment: I start the servce manually as dse so renaming should not be an issue. `ps auwx | grep dse`     casuser   21626  0.0  0.0  15940   936 pts/9    S+   07:10   0:00 grep --color=auto dse

Comment: `user 21626 0.0 0.0 15940 936 pts/9 S+ 07:10 0:00 grep --color=auto dse` is actually the `grep` command you issued, not the `dse` process itself.

Comment: I thought the grep is simply giving me details of dse process rather than all processes. The PID is what I am looking for of dse and it is giving me that.